# Setting name for list in class on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in an android application where I have a house that has a list of rooms. I am trying to find out how to use the name of the room as the value for the child rather than the 0 and 1.

The database structure is below

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Do not link to screenshots. The attached information could be given as **text**. Beyond that:

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Map<StringRoomName,RoomDetailsClass>` 
this will show `StringRoomName` in place of 0 and `RoomDetailsClass` as json object value. 
where StringRoomName = `String`

```
   class Room{
    //your other members
    Map<String,RoomDetailsClass> roomMap;
    // gettes and setters or constructor for initialization

    class RoomDetailsClass{

    //your room details

    }
  }
```

and upload it using

```
if (isDataValidatied()) {
                mDatabase.push().setValue(roomObject, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError == null) {
                            makeToast("One entry created successfully");
                            clearData();
                        } else {
                            makeToast("data creation failed");
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                makeToast("Please check data entered");
            }
```

Comment: The map was what I need, rather than putting them as a list

Comment: Hi @user3757775 please accept it as answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to change your database structure. You need to use in stead of `0`, `1` and so on the, the actual name of the room, `Kitchen`, `Living Room` and so on.

To display them, just put a `listener` on the `rooms` node and get the keys from the `dataSnapshot` object.

Hope it helps.